# landsat 8 images in ERDAS imagine 2014 is not mosaicking properly

Tags: erdas-imagine, mosaic

[image]

I am trying to merge all 4 landsat 8 images in order to create land use land cover map, but its not merging properly.I layerstacked this images before merging. Should i download landsat images which is captured in same day to mosaic it properly. All four images are captured on different dates.

Comment: You should make the histograms of the source images to match before making a mosaic. MosaicPro can do that automatically if you have a license.

Comment: Not sure but from what I see you, you are in the wrong position to merge it. You need to use the Mosaic toolbox to do that ...

Comment: I did use mosaic tool box which consists of three mosaic options such as pro, from 2d view and express..the image in the picture is output mosaic

Comment: You will need to play it around using the color balancing in Moasic Pro...I'd go google on it and find it around....  or check this out..http://katrinamclean.com/erdas-radarsat-mosaick/